# Center one out of several <img>'s on the same line

Tags: html, css, image

I have one main title and three logos/icons. The icons are floated to the right, but my main image/title I want centered. It probably isn't working because of my floated icons on the same line, but how can I get around that, and center my main image based on the page width of 80%?

here is the HTML:

```
        <img src="reddit.jpeg" class="icons" id="reddit">
        <img src="stack.jpeg" class="icons" id="stackoverflow">
        <img src="dropbox.jpg" class="icons" id="dropbox">
        <img src="title.jpg" class="title">
```

CSS:

```
body {
width: 80%; /* 1150px*/
margin:0 auto;
}

.icons {
float: right;
margin:0 0.43478261%;
opacity:.5;
}

.title {
display:block;
margin:0.86956522% auto;
}
```

**EDIT:** http://jsfiddle.net/Nilzone/2bfhp/1/

Comment: Providing your code as a [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/) would probably help as people can then see it in context.

Comment: @nickhar http://jsfiddle.net/Nilzone/2bfhp/1/

Comment: If the title stays centred, what do you expect the 3 icons to do when the screen-width is decreased?

Comment: @nickhar I have added a '@media' class which takes care of that.

Answer (score 0):

I made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mE8mx/1/) using divs (block type) instead of images (inline-block type).  I gave the divs widths and bg-colors so that they are visible.  And I made sure that your icons won't accidentally be covered by using a min-width.

---

Edit:

I used a div around the picture that is absolutely positioned and centered horizontally by using `left:50%`.  And then I added a `left:-50%;` to the image itself so that it will be centered on the page.

```
.title {
    left:50%;
    position:absolute;
    width:100px;
    height:auto;
}
.title img{
    left:-50%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mE8mx/2/

Comment: Did you look at the jsfiddle?  I'll try it again using images instead of divs to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Have a look at my fiddle :)

Comment: I have edited my comment to reflect the fact that images and divs are very different.

Comment: sadly, no. Maybe I just implement it wrong - but please use my fiddle and show me. I think that would be the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

I'd wrap the icons in a div and position it against the right border, out of the document flow, and treat the title image as a run-of-the-mill banner: http://jsfiddle.net/2bfhp/2/

```
<div class='icon-set'>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/S5JcLk9.jpg" class="icons" id="reddit"/>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/8xLxjd5.jpg" class="icons" id="stackoverflow"/>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/uFny2Mp.jpg" class="icons" id="dropbox"/>
</div>
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/CcTWeln.jpg" class="title">
```

and

```
body {
    width: 80%;
    /* 1150px*/
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
.icon-set {
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
}
```